# Prove or disprove that {$1,x,x^2,...$} is a basis of the space of complex sequences

Tags: vector-spaces

By $x^n$ I mean the sequence $(1,2^n,3^n,...)$. 
My attempt :

Take any sequence $(z_0,z_1,z_2,...)$. I need to find scalars $x_i$ such that
$(z_0,z_1,z_2,...)=x_0(1,1,1,...)+x_1(1,2,3,...)+x_2(1,2^2,3^2,...)+...$

Next I considered the system of equations :

$x_0+x_1+x_2+...+x_n=z_0$
$x_0+2x_1+2^2x_2+...+2^nx_n=z_1$

$.$

$.$

$x_0+(n+1)x_1+(n+1)^2x_2+...+(n+1)^nx_n=z_n$

The coefficient matrix is a vandermonde  matrix whose determinant is nonzero. So the above system has a unique solution. The uniqueness proves that {$1,x,...,x^n$} is linearly independent for each $n$, and hence, the set {$1,x,x^2,...$} is linearly independent. 
But I'm not quite sure how to show that it is a spanning set. This is all that I could do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these finite sequences?

Comment: Are you considering infinite sums? In this case you should specify that the **closed span** of your vectors is the whole space of complex sequences

Comment: @MiloBrandt no. That's why I couldn't conclude that they span the whole space.

Comment: @JayTuma I'm sorry I don't know what a closed span is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $(1,0,0,0,0\cdots)$ is not expressible as a linear combination of *finitely many* of your sequences. Therefore your sequences do not make up a basis.

Let’s look at this a little more abstractly. Your sequences $\{x_n\}$, defined more fully as $x_i(m)=m^i$, are just the ordinary, every-day monomials of the polynomial ring $\Bbb R[X]$, if you’re allowing real scalars, which we might as well do. Any linear combination of your sequences will give a *polynomial* function $\sum_{i=0}^Ma_iX^i$, finitely many terms.

But it’s a basic fact about real polynomials $\,f$ is that if $\,f$ has infinitely many zeros, then $\,f$ is the zero-polynomial. My counterexample has infinitely many zeros, but is not the zero-function. Thus it’s not a polynomial function, and so not expressible as a finite linear combination of your sequences.

Comment: I see. So even the set {$(1,0,0,0,...),(0,1,0,0,...),(0,0,1,0,...),(0,0,0,1,...),...$} isn't a basis because $(1,1,1,1,...)$ cannot be written as a finite linear combination of them.

Comment: Right you are. In fact, the space of sequences is not merely infinite-dimensional, the dimension is the cardinality of the continuum. Infinity is infinitely mysterious !

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Your sequeces are indeed linealy independent, but they don't span the space of all sequences. For instance, the sequence $(1,2^2,3^6,4^{24},\ldots,n^{n!},\ldots)$ cannot be written as a linear combination of $x_n$'s; it growths too fast for that.

Comment: I am not able to see why it isn't a linear combination of $x^n$s. Could you please explain a little?

Comment: Suppose that my sequence is $a_1{x_1}^n+a_2{x_2}^n+\cdots+a_k{x_k}^n$. You can assume withou loss of generality that $|x_1|\leqslant|x_2|\leqslant\cdots\leqslant|x_k|$. Now, you are saying that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):n^{n!}=a_1{x_1}^n+\cdots+a_k{x_k}^n.$$But this implies that$$\frac{n^{n!}}{{x_k}^n}=a_1\left(\frac{x_1}{x_k}\right)^n+\cdots+a_{n-1}\left(\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_k}\right)^n+a_n.$$This can't be, because the LHS is unbounded, whereas the RHS converges to $a_k$.